# How to implement double tap for Android live wallpapers?

Tags: android, live-wallpaper

I want to implement a double tap event for a Android live wallpaper.
Sadly, I couldn´t find any specific code how to do that.

At the moment I´ve found a workarround using the onTouchEvent-method of the Engine-class:

```
public void onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
  long time = android.os.SystemClock.currentThreadTimeMillis();

  if(((time - mLastTouchTime) < 500) && ((time - mLastTouchTime) > 100))
  {
    if(!mIsPlayed && mSound)
      {
        mIsPlayed = true;
        int sound = R.raw.hell;
        if(mTheme.equals("rose"))
          sound = R.raw.rose;
        if(mTheme.equals("greed"))
          sound = R.raw.greed;

        MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(), sound);   
          mp.start();
          mp.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
      @Override
      public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        mp.release();
        mIsPlayed = false;
      }
    });
      }
  }

  mLastTouchTime = time;
  super.onTouchEvent(event);
}
```

Well, that´s not an elegant solution. I know there are wallpapers which implemented the double tap. But I have no idea, how to do it on my own.

So a "tap" in the right direction would be nice. If nescessary, I will accept a "double tap". :D

Greetings,
Robert

Comment: For your information: the android standard keyboard handle double taps exactly the same way as you do. I therefore assume there's no better solution to do this ;)

Comment: Thank you for that information. Is there any example code where I can find the right values for the time intervals?

Comment: I think it's up to you to choose :) I remember that android keyboard double-tap delay is set to something like 800ms. Android source is down, I did not verify this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/GestureDetector.html

for example:

```
public class AndroidTestActivity extends Activity {

    private GestureDetector gestureDetector;

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener(){
            @Override
            public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent e) {
                Log.e("onDoubleTap", e.toString());
                //handle double tap
                return true;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Daniel, thank you for your answer. I am a little confused, because I tried that and got no result. However, now it is working perfectly. This solution is definitly the preferred way to catch a double tap event. Big Thanks! :)

Comment: @xong please xong help! I am trying to do the same as you did. PLEASE COULD YOU POST YOUR CODE??? Thanks a lot!!! LISA