# Change Wallpaper on double tap on empty space of home screen

Tags: android

I am looking for a Scenario.

suppose i double tap on a homescreen, what i want is that my app changes the homescreen wallpaper.Any idea what should i use?

Service or any Broadcast or wallpaper Manager class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either build your own home screen or live wallpaper. Go through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7633110/3074922) answer.